# Multi tab form with validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a code which hide and show div in the multi tab form. Form contains radiobox, checkbox and input text fields.

```
<a href="#" id="prev" class="hide">Previous </a> <a href="#" id="next"> Next</a>
<hr /> 

<div id="main">   
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="">
<div id="div1" class="first current">
    <label for="option1">Option 1:</label> <input type="radio" name="RadioOption" id="option1" value="Option 1" />      <br/>
    <label for="option2">Option 2:</label> <input type="radio" name="RadioOption" id="option2" value="Option 2" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <label for="answer1">First question?</label> <input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer1" value="" />
    <br/>
    <label for="answer2">Second question?</label> <input type="text" name="answer2" id="answer2" value="" />
</div>
<div id="div3" class="last">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkit" id="check1" value="check1" /> CheckBox 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkit" id="check2" value="check2" /> CheckBox 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkit" id="check3" value="check3" /> CheckBox 3<br/>
    Thank you for your time. Press submit.
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</div>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KpHBL/1/**

I want to add simple validation, user need to choose on of the option to be able to click "Next" in first step (div1). Then in second step (div2) have to answer for first question, second is optional. In third step (div3) it would be great if user could check only 2 checkboxes out of 3, no matter which ones.

It will be nice if there was some info while clicking "Next" and radio or answer is missing, like "You have to choose the option", "This field can't be empty", etc.

I want to add a lot more input elements but i need just an example and I will take it from there.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use jquery validation engine for your requirement... for more just visit this demo page.. http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

Comment: As you can see at jsfiddle, button "Next" it's "global" (above tabs) so it would have to check active tab (div) only. How can I do that?

Comment: you can just use several forms in your html page to do that... and on next click change forms....